# C# Passing Generic Class as a parameter to a custom Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that can take in the following parameters.

1. Class Type - **classType**
2. Page Number - **pageNum**
3. Page Size - **pageSize**
4. Order by Column - **orderByColumn**

Below is an example of the function that I'm trying to replicate.

```
 public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(IList<T> classType, int pageNum, int pageSize, string orderByColumn)
       {
        if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 10;  // TODO: Default pageSize for the Moment
        if (pageNum <= 0) pageNum = 1;
        int excludedRows = (pageNum - 1) * pageSize;

        return GetRepo<classType>().All(null).AsQueryable().Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(p => p.orderByColumn).Skip(excludedRows).Take(pageSize).ToList();                                  
    }
```

I'm uncertain of how it should pass the **classType** and the **orderByColumn** to the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the "class type".. its `T`:

```
GetRepo<T>().All(null)...
```

For the `OrderBy`.. pass in a delegate yourself:

```
public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(IList<T> classType, 
                                 int pageNum, 
                                 int pageSize, 
                                 Func<T, object> orderBy)
{
    ...

    return ... ... .OrderBy(orderBy)
}
```

And pass the delegate in like this:

```
GetDataPerPage(..., ..., ..., x => x.SomePropertyHere);
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon Whitehead. I got the class to be passed by only with adding the **where T : class** at the end of the end name else the T will return compile error. `public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(Func<T, object> whereClause, Func<T, object> orderByClause, int pageNum, int pageSize) where T : class`. I used your _Func<T, object> orderBy_ for a where clause in the function as that might change from class to class but it does not accept the whereBy clause.

Comment: This is the error I get from the whereby clause `'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource, bool>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Hi @SimonWhitehead, I got the whereBy clause to work by passing through the parameter as `Func<T, bool>`

Comment: Sorry it was the middle of the night here while you were replying. Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to pass the `classType` parameter at all, because you will declare the type `T` when you use the `GetDataPerPage<T>()` method, so change it to this:

```
public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(int pageNum, int pageSize, string orderByColumn)
{
    if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 10;  // TODO: Default pageSize for the Moment
    if (pageNum <= 0) pageNum = 1;
    int excludedRows = (pageNum - 1) * pageSize;

    return GetRepo<T>().All(null)
                       .AsQueryable()
                       .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false)
                       .OrderBy(p => p.orderByColumn)
                       .Skip(excludedRows)
                       .Take(pageSize)
                       .ToList();                                  
}
```

---

As for the `orderByColumn` parameter, if you are going to just do a comparison like your example, then passing in a `string` is fine, but if you want to control the logic of the comparison to use a `string` property of type `T`, then pass a delegate like this:

```
public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(int pageNum, int pageSize, Func<T, string> orderBy)
{
    if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 10;  // TODO: Default pageSize for the Moment
    if (pageNum <= 0) pageNum = 1;
    int excludedRows = (pageNum - 1) * pageSize;

    return GetRepo<T>().All(null)
                       .AsQueryable()
                       .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == false)
                       .OrderBy(orderBy)
                       .Skip(excludedRows)
                       .Take(pageSize)
                       .ToList();                                  
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = GetDataPerPage<T>(pageNum, pageSize, p => p.Property1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Karl Anderson. I remove the _IList<T> classType_ and added `where T: class` at the end of the function and that accepts the entity. I created a `Func<T, string>` parameter for the where clause but that breaks when trying to pass in `p => p.IsDeleted == false`. I corrected by that by changing it to a `Func<T, bool>`. **How would you be able to pass through a like SQL statement to the function if it only accepts a boolean value?**

Comment: @pchannon - I originally answered the question using `Func<T, bool>`, but since you are using this in the `OrderBy()` function, then doesn't it need to be a `string`? I thought you wanted the ability to select which property of your domain object you wanted to sort by or am I incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I would like to. Should the function look like this instead? `public List<T> GetDataPerPage<T>(Func<T, bool> whereClause, Func<T, object> orderByClause, int pageNum, int pageSize) where T : class
{
if (pageSize <= 0) pageSize = 10;  // TODO: Default pageSize for the Moment
if (pageNum <= 0) pageNum = 1;
int excludedRows = (pageNum - 1) * pageSize;

return GetRepo<T>().All(null).AsQueryable().Where(whereClause).OrderBy(orderByClause).Skip(excludedRows).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}`

Comment: @pchannon - If you want to just pass string property values to the `OrderBy()` function of your query, then yes this should work, but try it out and decide for yourself. I just wanted to make sure I understood what you were trying to do, that's all. :-)